# designing a web-cms database for an assignment

Tags: database-design, content-management-system

I am designing a database system for a web CMS. I have added the "status" column in the "Content" table which shows the status of each content in a time. I know there are only some special values which status can accept like : 'draft', 'comment waiting', authorizing pending' and... I want to create a check constraint to make this column to accept only above values. is it a correct work?
what are the whole of the status values which i can use in my constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Use `enum()` for data type of the status column. e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
   ...
   status enum('draft','comment waiting','etc.') not null,
   ...
);
```